# PHP Scraping - file_get_contents redirect limit?

Tags: php, html, redirect, screen-scraping, file-get-contents

I'm trying to scrape the courses from ASU's schedule of classes page.

I'm doing something like this:

```
$url = "https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist?s=PSY&t=2117&e=all&hon=F";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
echo $html;
```

Now, when I go to a classes page loads listing all of the pysch classes. But, when I try to echo the above URL (which isn't broken) I get an error about "redirect limit reached, aborting...".

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Are you sure you are even authorized to grab that content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get an error about "redirect limit reached, aborting...".

This is something you probably can't do anything about. You are getting this error because the page you requested keeps redirecting in a way that it cannot end (loop redirection).

That's a problem on the page you are requesting.

Chances that you're getting a redirect is because of certain headers / cookies that the page require and you cannot supply through the use of `file_get_contents()`. Try using the [cURL Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead.

Comment: How exactly could I fix this using the code library? Do you have a snippet of code perhaps?

Comment: Search around SO on how to use cURL. Repeating that here will probably be quite off topic,  especially when you're not providing much for us to help you.